# How to close WPF application from context menu?

Tags: wpf, command

Is there a *command* in WPF to close the application from context menu? That is, the same context menu which you get by right clicking on the title bar on any window?

There are loads of standard commands, but I am struggling to find an exit *command*.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unfortunately this doesn't exist. You'll have to implement a custom command and call

```
Application.Current.Shutdown();
```

Comment: It is probably Application.Current.Shutdown(); as Application.Current.Exit(); is an event.

Answer (score 1):

There is an ApplicationCommands.Close, but there is not an ApplicationCommands.Exit.

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286692/wpf-standard-commands-wheres-exit) (for example) to find alternatives (such as creating a custom command).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is solved. But following code may help others.

```
     Environment.Exit(0)
```

Comment: I think the Application.Current.Shutdown should be used instead. IIRC, Env.Exit is quite a harsh action comparable to killing the process directly. But I may be plainly wrong. Unfortunatelly, I dont have reflector at hand to verify it.

Comment: Yes Environment.Exit(0) is a very brutal way for closing your application. It releases all resources of your application and get back to OS environment.

Answer (score 0):

Not that complex actually (but still, M$ sucks for not providing it). Here you go:

```
public static class MyCommands
{
    private static readonly ICommand appCloseCmd = new ApplicationCloseCommand();
    public static ICommand ApplicationCloseCommand
    {
        get { return appCloseCmd; }
    }
}

//===================================================================================================
public class ApplicationCloseCommand : ICommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        // You may not need a body here at all...
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return Application.Current != null && Application.Current.MainWindow != null;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Close();
    }
}
```

And the body of the `AplicationCloseCommand.CanExecuteChanged` event handler may not be even needed.

You use it like so:

```
<MenuItem Header="{DynamicResource MenuFileExit}" Command="MyNamespace:MyCommands.ApplicationCloseCommand"/>
```

Cheers!

(You cannot imagine how long it took me to discover this Command stuff myself...)

Comment: little trick resharper told me: my compete body of the `MyCommands` class: `public static ICommand ApplicationCloseCommand { get; } = new ApplicationCloseCommand();`

Comment: @OlleKelderman Yes. This is C# version 6 syntax. That answer predates it. :)

Comment: I know, still useful for anyone being here by search engine :)