# What is default closing event in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf

This is C# WPF application. I have a `Button` that close the application. Is there a default close event as that of the **(x)** button of the top right corner of the Window.

Basically I hope there is a pure XAML solution like the following:

```
<Button CloseWhenClick></Button>
```

Instead of this:

```
<Button Click="CloseWindow_Click"></Button>

private void Close(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window.Close();
}
```

**[EDIT - ANSWER]**

What I was looking for:

```
<Button Command="Close"></Button>
```

Comment: any specific reason for `Pure XAML` solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such consept like "default" closing event, but thre is in WPF a Command concept. Bind your relay command to that button and you done. Here is a link on Q&A : [WPF Standard Commands - Where's Exit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286692/wpf-standard-commands-wheres-exit).

Hope this helps.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    public App()
    {
        Exit += new ExitEventHandler(App_Exit);
    }

    void App_Exit(object sender, ExitEventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO : are you sure ?!!
    }
```

hope this help

Comment: @S.Aamani: as the question mentioned, I am looking for a possibility of a XAML solution

Answer (score 0):

Not that complex actually (but still, M$ sucks for not providing it). Here you go:

```
public static class MyCommands
{
    private static readonly ICommand appCloseCmd = new ApplicationCloseCommand();
    public static ICommand ApplicationCloseCommand
    {
        get { return appCloseCmd; }
    }
}

//===================================================================================================
public class ApplicationCloseCommand : ICommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        // You may not need a body here at all...
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return Application.Current != null && Application.Current.MainWindow != null;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Close();
    }
}
```

And the body of the `AplicationCloseCommand.CanExecuteChanged` event handler may not be even needed.

You use it like so:

```
<MenuItem Header="{DynamicResource MenuFileExit}" Command="MyNamespace:MyCommands.ApplicationCloseCommand"/>
```

Cheers!

(You cannot imagine how long it took me to discover this Command stuff myself...)